# Reduce repetition when sharing data across an application

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter 3 application. There is some data every page across the application needs to have.

This is the system I currently have.

**Create a model function that will get the data I need**

```
Class General_model extends CI_Model
{
    function data_init()
    {
        $data['session'] = $this->session->userdata('session');
        $data['foobar'] = $this->general_model->get_foobar();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**In every controller, I call this data in the __construct()**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('general_model', '', TRUE);
    $this->data = $this->general_model->data_init();
}
```

**I begin every controller function by getting the data in the scope of the function, which then gets passed to the view**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = $this->data;
    $data['page_title'] = 'example';
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('page/example', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

I feel this is not ideal. It feels repetitive and not dry to have `$this->data = $this->general_model->data_init();` in every constructor and `$data = $this->data;` in every function.

It feels like it'd be better if I could declare `$this->data = $this->general_model->data_init();` once in the application and have `$this->data` available to every function in every controllers. I'd also like to avoid `$data = $this->data;` at the start of every function, but I'd rather do that than have the additional 7 characters `$this->` hundreds of times across the codebase (perhaps that is me being lazy?).

I'm not sure how to improve either of those without breaking OOP and going global, or touching CodeIgniter core classes such as `CI_Model`.

**Is there a way to improve how I'm sharing and moving this data?**

Comment: What sort of improvement are you looking for specifically?

Comment: 3rd to last paragraph. Specifically, to stop repeating myself, which I feel I do by having `$this->data = $this->general_model->data_init();` in every constructor and `$data = $this->data;` in every function.

Comment: Move that code up to `CI_Model`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey CI_Model is the CodeIgniter core, and I believe it's good practice not to touch a frameworks core.

Comment: OK.  Create your own `CI_Model_Extended` class that extends `CI_Model`, and put your code *there.*  Have your subsequent classes inherit `CI_Model_Extended` instead of `CI_Model`.

Comment: As you can see, this is a tradeoff, like most everything else in software development.  You might be better off simply remaining slightly less DRY.

Comment: Maybe. Seems kind of messy. I'd have a bunch of real controller then one that is there just to solve this one problem. I agree there's tradeoffs, I hope this question helps me find what my options are. You should post your idea as an answer, even if it's not ideal.

Comment: Composition is also an option.  But this is not all that verbose; have you seen any Enterprise Java code recently?  BTW, DRY doesn't mean "one function call instead of three."  Technically, your code is already DRY, because it consists *only of function calls.*  At the end of the day, it's just a simple refactor, but those three function calls have to live *somewhere.*

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `$this->data` is a property of a controller class defined like this.

```
class Some_controller extends CI_Controller
{
   protected $data;  //could be public or private too, not relevant to the discussion

  function __construct()
  {
     //assign a value to the $data property
     $this->data = $this->general_model->data_init();
  }
```

If so, then the points about memory utilization in Mike's answer could be realized simply by using `$this->data` directly in each controller method. Making a copy (i.e. `$data = $this->data;`) is pointless because the property is already available to all controller methods. In other words, simply do this in any class method.

```
$this->data['page_title'] = 'example';
```

Then pass the class property (`$data`) to the view load like this.

```
$this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
```

In the revised `index()` below I have done a couple other things that probably amount to "micro-optimizations" but are worth considering. First, notice I only pass `$this->data` to the first `load->view()` call.

The documentation doesn't do a great job of pointing out that any data passed via `load->view()` is cached and will be available to any subsequent views loaded. If you continually pass exactly the same data you are running many extra lines of code that simply overwrite the cached data with the exact same values. If you don't pass any data this pointless exercise is eliminated.

The second "micro-optimization" is the use of *method chaining*. `load->view()` returns a `CI_Loader` instance which is exactly the same memory location that `$this->load` returns. Why make it look up that value again? And why do all the extra typing?

```
public function index()
{
  $this->data['page_title'] = 'example';
  $this->load
    ->view('templates/header', $this->data)
    ->view('page/example')
    ->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Now, with all that said, the thing that will help you the most with being DRY is to create a "base controller" that will extend `CI_Controller`. This "base controller" is then used to create all the other controllers for the application. Refer to the CI documentation about [Extending Native Libraries](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#extending-native-libraries) for details but the basic idea starts with creating the "base controller".

Create the file `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $data;  

    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('general_model', '', TRUE);
      $this->data = $this->general_model->data_init();
    }
```

The property `$data` will be available in any class that extends `MY_Controller` so use it as the base class for all other application controllers.

Since you appear to use the same set of header and footer views all the time you can also DRY out view loading.

`MY_Controller` continues with:

```
  /**
   * A template used for every page load
   * @param string $view is the name of the view file to load
   * @param array $view_data is data to be passed to view files. 
   * If no $view_data is passed then the class property $data is used
   */
  public function render_page($view, $view_data = NULL)
  {
    //Uses a ternary to decide what "data" gets sent to view
    $this->load
      ->view('templates/header', isset($view_data) ? $view_data : $this->data)
      ->view($view)
      ->view('templates/footer');
  }

} //end of MY_Controller
```

The following uses the CI "Welcome" example modified by extending with `MY_Controller`. It adds an "other_page" too.

This is the file `application/controllers/Welcome.php`

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    //If desired you could set a default title for pages of this controller
    $this->data["page_title"] = "Welcome";
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->render_page('welcome_message');
  }

  public function other_page()
  {
    //overwrite the default page title
    $this->data["page_title"] = "Other Page";
    $this->render_page('other_view');
  }

}
```

Hopefully it is clear how this achieves the goals described in your question.

A couple last comments on what seems to be unnecessary work.

First, it appears you have set some session data that might look something like this. (Obviously, I'm making up keys and values.)

```
$_SESSION['session'] = array('id`=>$id, 'name'=>'Guy', 'logged_in'=>TRUE);
```

Putting an array in an array seems to me to be making more work than needed. Just set each item as a key in `$_SESSION` directly.

```
$_SESSION['some_key'] = $some_value;
```

If you look at the source code for `set_userdata()` the above is essentially what you will find. IMO, the best reason to use `set_userdata()` is to set several items at once.

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>'Guy', 'logged_in'=> TRUE));
```

That line produces **exactly** the same thing as these lines.

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Guy';
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
```

The second 'final comment' is about making a copy of session data in your model with this call.

```
$data['session'] = $this->session->userdata('session');
```

Clearly you have the `session` library running and it contains previously set user data.

The `session` class can be used directly in every controller method so why make a copy of its data? Making a copy uses more memory and forces you to dereference the copy in order to utilize it -  for example:

```
$user_name = $this->data['session']['user_name'];
```

Why do something like that when, if you set the session data as suggested earlier, you could use any of the following in any controller method?

```
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']; //runs the risk of an "Undefined index" error
```

or

```
$user_name = $this->session->user_name; //using the "magic" getter - my prefered way to go
```

or

```
$user_name =  $this->session->userdata('user_name'); // the "traditional" CI way
```

Comment: This approach has it's own disadvantages too, however it definitely answers the question. I probably won't retrofit my existing apps, but will attempt this on my next project.

Comment: Follow up, I'm fairly certain that what you're saying on sessions is incorrect if I'm understanding you correctly. In particular "That line produces exactly the same thing as these lines.". A `var_dump` on `$_SESSION` shows that a CodeIgniter session will contains two top level elements, `__ci_last_regenerate` and `session`. `session` will then contain the elements defined.

Comment: If you are seeing an item called `session` then there is some code in your test that is adding it to the user data. Perhaps a call like `$this->session->set_userdata('session', 'some_value');` or `$_SESSION['session'] = 'some_value';`  The `__ci_last_regenerate` item is added by CI's session class automatically. It is used internally by the `session` library.

Comment: Not to take away from the great answer, but I'm still fairly certain wrong on CodeIgniter sessions. You should do `$this->session->set_userdata(array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>'Guy', 'logged_in'=> TRUE));` then `var_dump($_SESSION);` as I just did and perhaps you'll see those variables stored inside an index called session. In general, the session library does a lot of magic and your answer could make it more clear that it's not recommended to ever side step with direct `$_SESSION` usage if you plan to use the session library.

Comment: @Goose, I did exactly what you suggested before making my previous comment. There is no `$_SESSION['session']` unless it is explicitly added to the session user data.

Comment: @Goose, your comment "it's not recommended to ever side step with direct $_SESSION usage" is completely wrong. If you check the official documentation on [Retrieving Session Data](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data) the first thing is says is "Any piece of information from the session array is available through the $_SESSION superglobal". A little further down the page in the Adding Session Data section is says, "You can simply assign data to the $_SESSION array, as with any other variable." This has been the case since the release of v3.0.0.

Comment: You might be right, I think I see my mistake here. I use v3.x, but I might be remembering documentation from v2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I would not get all worked up about having to type a few extra letters when referencing a variable.  I **could** get worked up over possibly doubling the storage space required for your data depending on it's size. Let's walk though what PHP is doing behind the scenes here to understand:

```
// PHP references $this->data to $data by reference
$data = $this->data;

// since you modify $data here, PHP now copies the entirety of $this->data
// to $data and breaks reference
// you are now taking up double (plus some) storage for your data 
$data['page_title'] = 'example';
```

As opposed to directly modifying `$this->data` before making assignment to `$data` like shown below , which would not double memory utilization:

```
$this->data['page_title'] = 'example';
$data = $this->data;
```

Just remember that as soon as you modify an array assigned in this manner, you remove the ability for PHP to perform it's behind the scenes memory optimization. But really you should not be relying on this anyway, as IMO it is bad coding form to be relying on some hidden, undocumented and possibly subject to change optimization for your code to be working in the best manner.

Alternately, instead of associative array for data, why not use an object (even `stdClass`), then you are **always** working with reference to the object (unless you specifically clone it)? For example:

```
// assuming $this->data holds object
// $data is just reference to $this->data here
$data = $this->data;

// here modifying $data would modify both $data and $this->data
$data->page_title = 'example';
```

This also gives you the possible side benefit of being able to type hint against an object in method signatures as you are passing this data around or injecting it as dependency.